# Not able to parse api response

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an api response that looks like so…I get the response from the api properly..

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "meta": {
            "url": "htt..://www.abc.com",
            "title": “ASD - Log In or Sign Up",
            "description": "Create an account or log in….”,
            "display_url": "htt..://www.abc.com/",
            "video_url": "",
            "image": "htt..://www.asd.com/images/asds_325x325.png",
            "img_wxh": "325x325"
        }
    }
}
```

The model class with which I parse this data is given like so..

```
struct MetaData: Codable {
  let status: String?
  let data: DataClass?
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
  let meta: Meta
}

struct Meta: Codable {
  let url: String
  let title, description: String
  let displayURL: String
  let videoURL: String
  let image: String
  let imgWxh: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case url = "url"
    case title = "title"
    case description = "description"
    case displayURL = "display_url"
    case videoURL = "video_url"
    case image = "image"
    case imgWxh = "img_wxh"
  }
}
```

The api call that is being made is gives as below...

```
 WebServiceClient.shared.getMeta(withParameters: parameters) { [weak self] (isSuccess, result) in
      guard let `self` = self else { return }
      if isSuccess, result != nil {


        if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result as Any, options: []) {
          do {
            let metaData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MetaData.self, from: jsonData)


            self.metaDataImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: metaData.data?.meta.image ?? ""), completed: nil)
            self.urlLabel.text = metaData.data?.meta.url
            self.titleLabel.text = metaData.data?.meta.title
            self.urlDescriptionLabel.text = metaData.data?.meta.description

          } catch {
            print("error \(error)")
          }
        }
      }
```

But I get all data as nil...what could be the reason..?

I get nothing in `metaData`...

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your API returns the JSON as you expect. Because from your debugger screenshot, I can see that `url` have `status` string and `description` as `success` .

Comment: @asd2: print `jsonData` and check if json sent by server actually contains all the data or not

Comment: instead of using jsonSerialization, use:
`if let result = response.result.value {
                let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                print(JSON)
            let metaData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MetaData.self, from: JSON)

            }`

Comment: Why you want to cast it to `NSDictionary`? @SanadBarjawi
It's `Data` type.

Comment: Try to use let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)            Then pass it to the JSONDecoder

Comment: Your main issue which causes all your similar questions is `WebServiceClient`. What is its benefit? This serialization dance is horrible and very inefficient. Can `WebServiceClient` return raw `Data`? If yes, use the `Data` output for `JSONDecoder`.  If not, look for a better API. If you can't drop `WebServiceClient` parse the dictionary the traditional way with key and index subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I tried to parse your data

```
struct MetaData: Codable {
    let status: String?
    let data: DataClass?
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let meta: Meta
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let url: String
    let title, description: String
    let displayURL: String
    let videoURL: String
    let image: String
    let imgWxh: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url = "url"
        case title = "title"
        case description = "description"
        case displayURL = "display_url"
        case videoURL = "video_url"
        case image = "image"
        case imgWxh = "img_wxh"
    }
}

let jsonString = """
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
"meta": {
"url": "htt..://www.abc.com",
"title": "ASD - Log In or Sign Up ",
"description": "Create an account or log in….",
"display_url": "htt..://www.abc.com/",
"video_url": "",
"image": "htt..://www.asd.com/images/asds_325x325.png",
"img_wxh": "325x325"
}
}
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
do {
    let parsedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MetaData.self, from: jsonData!)
    print(parsedData)

} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

And it works.

[image]

Also your json have some issue so make sure you validate your json format.
you can use [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com) for validating json.

Comment: But what do I give in place of jsonString @Aks..?

Comment: I tried something like this...`        let jsonData = result?.description.data(using: .utf8)
        do {
          let parsedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MetaData.self, from: jsonData!)
        } catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
` But still I get nothing in `parsedData`

Comment: Can you post your `WebServiceClient.shared.getMeta(withParameters: parameters)` method definition?